# How do I remove brackets with specific texts?

Tags: excel

How do I replace specific text in brackets in excel? Would I use the replace function or the substitute function? I know this maybe a simple solution but I am pretty confused.

Please see example below. I am trying to remove brackets that contain (Number m).

[image]

Comment: You're looking for a formula and not just replacing the text using the `CNTL+H` function?

Comment: Looking for a formula. Some rows I do not want to apply the formula. Up there is just an example of what I am trying to perform on excel

Comment: also if I do 'CNTL+H' , what would I need to provide in the replace column? (* m) seems to remove all ()

Comment: I'd use VBA to create a User Defined Function using Regular Expressions to implement your logic.